# How does game difficulty work in a multiplayer game?

Tags: civilization-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when two players play the same game at different difficulties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24080/what-happens-when-two-players-play-the-same-game-at-different-difficulties)

I play a cooperative game with another human, with all the other players being AI. Apparently every human can choose difficulty separately - she chose prince difficulty and I chose Emperor difficulty.

Looking at [What changes are made when playing King through to Deity difficulty?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10152/what-changes-are-made-when-playing-king-through-to-deity-difficulty), I see some aspects of the difficulty affect the player - such as base happiness - and I understand how it works in a multiplayer game; but many aspects affect the AI players.

Since we chose different difficulties, what exactly is the effect on the AI? Are they all prince-level AI? Emperor-level? Some this and some that? Somewhere in-between?